# how to output text in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I'm new to Prolog and I'm trying to write some output.

I have a function: `father(X,Y)` that is true if X is Y's father, so this happens:

```
?- father(homer,bart)
true
```

How do I do something like this:

```
doTests :-
  write('Test1 expect true ==> '),(write father(homer,bart)),nl,
  write('Test2 expect false ==> '),(write father(homer,nelson)),nl,
  write('Test3 expect true ==> '),(write father(abe,homer)).
```

so I get something like this ...

```
?- doTests.
Test1 expect true ==> true
Test2 expect false ==> false
Test3 expect true ==> true
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would factorize the pattern:

```
:- meta_predicate oneTest(+,:).

oneTest(Label, Pred) :- 
   (call(Pred) -> R = true ; R = false), format('~s ==> ~s~n', [Label, R]).

doTests :-
  oneTest('Test1 expect true', father(homer,bart)),
  oneTest('Test2 expect false', father(homer,nelson)),
  oneTest('Test3 expect true', father(abe,homer)).
```

Answer (score 0):

testfather :-
         father(homer, bart),
         writeln('Yes Homer is barts father').

if homer isn't bart's father, you'll never get to the writeln

if you want to print out a variable, do this

testfather :-
         father(X, bart),
         write(X),
         write(' is the father of bart'),
         nl.